# Iterating through a Dictionary and adding a value to every dictionary value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'd like to add 1 to every value in the Dictionary.

Produces "InvalidOperationException: out of sync"

```
    public Dictionary<int,int> dict = new Dictionary<int,int>();
    dict.Add (23, 34);

foreach (KeyValuePair<int,int> kvp in dict) {
        dict [kvp.Key] += 1;
    }
```

Here's the full error message:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Enumerator[System.Int32,System.Int32].VerifyState () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:912)
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Enumerator[System.Int32,System.Int32].MoveNext () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:835)
```

This attempt gives a similiar outcome:

```
foreach (int x in dict.Keys) {
            kek [x] += 1;
        }
```

Comment: have you tried dict.ToList(), this may be the problem because KVP are readonly so you are having to add and remove from the collection, this breaks the enumerable that the foreach is running off, calling tolist makes a copy of the collection and enumerates the copy not the original

Comment: Thanks, indeed it was it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach (int x in dict.Keys.ToList()) {
    dict[x] += 1;
}
```

as the dictionary gets invalidated on a change to it (and thus also its internal iterator).